# Azure app service need to be run at specific interval of time

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have hosted an webapplication and webapi in azure app service plan D1

Query 1 : Is it possible to apply the Private Certificate to the Shared Service plan

Query 2 : How to run my azure app service on specific interval of time . I dont want my website to run during night times. Is there any settings available to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Q1: Not possible, [see doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#app-service-limits)

Q2: You can stop your site using the Stop button in the Portal or by using the CLI. Note that this does not stop billing and there is no scheduling possible unless you implement something yourself.

```
az webapp stop --name MyWebapp --resource-group MyResourceGroup
```